# Prisma2: how to design schema which has relation with Array type Model?

Tags: node.js, database, database-design, graphql, prisma2

I faced some problems when designing the schema.

case 1:

```
model User {
  package: @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  packageId: Int
}

model Package {
  user User[]
}
```

one package can be subscribed by hundreds of users. So, I think this is the way to go. But, the problem is, when a package needs to be deleted, the user(admin) is also needed to be deleted. which we don't want

case 2:

```
model User {
  package Package[]
}

model package {
  author      User?  @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  authorId    Int?
}
```

by designing this way, when the package is deleted, the user is not deleted.
but I can't connect multiple users to a package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to explicitly model the relationship from both sides to get a [many-to-many relationship](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/tools-and-interfaces/prisma-schema/relations#many-to-many-relations). After all users can subscribe to many packages and packages can have many users subscribed.

```
model User {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  packages Package[] @relation(references: [id])
}

model Package {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  user User[] @relation(references: [id])
}
```